# Most popular Categories on Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got a 2 table 1 for categories and other for the posts that containts plain text.I've got an query which is getting categories that have relation with posts as you can see on the following segment.

```
$Categories = Assets::with(['posts'])->limit(4)->orderBy("view_count","DESC")->get();
```

My question is how can I get most popular posts (which has got an post more than others) ordered?

Comment: You mean the most popular categories? Which is defined by that with the most posts?

Comment: can you show the table structure for both the tables?

Comment: @James yes thats what I mean